# How can I fix a flexible dynamic stepper in react that changed based on active index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a stepper that contains 4 bullets.

So in default it looks like

**[1] - [2] - [3] - more**

When user clicks on [3]

Is will looks like :

**[more] - [4] - [5] - [more]**

And if they click on [5]

The last bullets will display as follow:

**[more] - [6] - [7]**

The default works now...but no clue on how to fix other scenarios?

```js
export const SfStickyFooter: FC<SfStickyFooterProps> = ({
  steps,
  activeStep,
  onChange,
}) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const breakpoint = useBreakpoint();
  const isMobile = breakpoint === "mobile";
  const isTablet = breakpoint === "tablet";

  const rotateArrow = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  const stepProperties = {
    mobile: 4,
    tablet: 5,
    desktop: steps.length,
    lineWidth: "80%",
  };

  return (
    <SfStickerFooter isOpen={isOpen}>
      <SfStickyFooterBackground width={"186px"} height={"125px"} />
      <SfArrowWrap onClick={rotateArrow}>
        <SfArrow width={"24px"} height={"24px"} color={"white"} />
      </SfArrowWrap>
      <SfStickyFooterContainer>
        {steps.map((item, index) => (
          <SfStickyFooterInnerContainer
            key={index}
            mobileSteps={stepProperties.mobile}
            tabletSteps={stepProperties.tablet}
            desktopSteps={stepProperties.desktop}
            stepsLineWidth={stepProperties.lineWidth}
            toggle={index <= activeStep}
          >
            <SfStickyFooterButton
              key={index}
              onClick={() => onChange(index, steps[index])}
            >
              {index}
            </SfStickyFooterButton>
            <SfStickyFooterBlock>
              {(isMobile && index === stepProperties.mobile - 1) ||
              (isTablet && index === stepProperties.tablet - 1)
                ? " More"
                : "Question " + [index + 1]}
            </SfStickyFooterBlock>
          </SfStickyFooterInnerContainer>
        ))}
      </SfStickyFooterContainer>
    </SfStickerFooter>
  );
};
```

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding -- what is it doing incorrectly, or what error are you seeing?

Comment: i am only displaying the default scenario.